# jQuery Synchrnus issue with alertifyjs success method

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, synchronous, alertifyjs

I m facing a strange issue. i have used alertify library to show messages to user, but in this case alertify is not working. Here is the success portion of my ajax call.

```
  success: function(data) {
       if (data.status == 'success') {
           alertify.success(data.msg);**// this line should dislay a message but instead of calling this , it directly calls employee_details(), data.msg is "Data saved Successfully"**; 
           data.user_type =3;
           if(data.hasOwnProperty('user_type')){
                if(data.user_type==2){
                    employeeDetails(data.id, tab_id);
                }else{
                    employee_details(data.id);
                }
            } else {
                return false;
            }

        }
    }
```

if i remove  employee_details(data.id), this works perfectly.

Comment: I don't know what kind of functions `employeeDetails` and `employee_details` are but looking at the code it could be that `employee_details` is `undefined` and it should be `employeeDetails(data.id);` in the else block instead?

Comment: The function is working fine, but alertify.success(data.msg) doesnt produce any result and  employee_details(data.id) get called because of user_type=3. So technically it should produce a popup alertify then go to employee_details(data.id). Dont focus on employee_details(data.id), it could be anything like a simple console.log("Hello);

Comment: With this snippet it is impossible to find the issue causing this problem. Can you provide a page where we can reproduce this behavior?